# Apparently "Gaming" is not a valid youtube category

Tags: php, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api, zend-gdata

I copied and pasted the example YouTube api code for browser-based uploading to my website, but it appears when I change the category to "Gaming", it gives me a bad request error.

Here is the example code:

```
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');
// The category must be a valid YouTube category!
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');

// Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
// and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');

$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];
```

However, when I change

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');
```

to

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Gaming');
```

I get..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain><code>invalid_value</code><location type='xpath'>media:group/media:category[@scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat']/text()</location></error></errors>
```

I have identified this as the only error. I have tried copying and pasting the word Gaming from the dropdown menu on the actual youtube upload form, to no avail (aren't I desperate).

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look into the error you got, and there was an url (http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat) in it. I downloaded the file and found the following line:

```
<atom:category term='Games' label='Gaming' xml:lang='en-US'><yt:assignable/><yt:browsable regions='AR AU BD BE BG BR CA CO CZ DE DK DZ EE EG ES ET FI FR GB GR HK HR HU ID IE IL IN IR IS IT JO JP KE KR LT LV MA MX MY NG NL NO NZ PH PK PL PT RO RS RU SA SE SG SI SK TH TN TR TW TZ UA UG US VN YE ZA'/></atom:category>
```

So I would try the term Games instead of Gaming.

```
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Games');
```